# How to display google form for muting native ad?

Tags: java, android, admob, ads, native-ads

I followed this guide https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/mute-this-ad

I used this code from github googlesamples too mute a **Native Ad**.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ads/blob/master/advanced/APIDemo/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/example/apidemo/AdMobCustomMuteThisAdFragment.java

But how can i get the same dialog as in the first image? Now i'm getting a simple dialog with the reasons.

**This is what i want**

[image]

**This is what i have now after following the guide and using code from googlesamples**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The GoogleSamples provides only the way to implement the Mute Ad option. Not the UI.

From their example, you only received **default short labels** (as "Inappropriate", "Repetitive"...) and use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` which is the **default list item** with only a `TextView` widget. As the first picture, in production they should use custom strings with their own user interface. According to the documentation you linked:

> **The implementation of the custom mute interface is entirely up to you**. You can place a small close button on the ad, or **you can provide some other interface for the user to opt to mute the ad**.

The solution might be to map the reasons with your own labels in `MuteThisAdReasonWrapper` into `toString()`, and use a custom list item instead of `simple_list_item_1`.

Comment: But what i want is the default google form with the reasons. As you can see in the first image the blue X close button i don't get that even when i remove setRequestCustomMuteThisAd(true). But i searched everywhere for the default implementation but can only find the one for a custom mute.

Comment: Did you set it to setRequestCustomMuteThisAd(false) and then check nativeAd.isCustomMuteThisAdEnabled() whether its getting set , So that you can confirm that its not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set it to `setRequestCustomMuteThisAd(false)` and then check `nativeAd.isCustomMuteThisAdEnabled()` whether its getting set , So that you can confirm that its not enabled.

Moreover check once, If you are building the adloader after you set it to false .

```
adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(context, "ad unit ID").withNativeAdOptions(new NativeAdOptions.Builder()
                         .setRequestCustomMuteThisAd(true)
                         .build()).build();
    adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

Comment: default value for setRequestCustomMuteThisAd is always false if not set, but i don't want to use a custom mute dialog. I want the one you can see in the first image, the ui provided by google.